# Memset POD struct with this pointer

Tags: c++

I have many POD struct with a lot of member variables. Instead of initializing each members in the constructor, I simply use memset. Is this valid in C++?

```
struct foo
{
    foo() { std::memset(this, 0, sizeof (foo)); }

    int var1;
    float var2;
    double var3;
    // more variables..
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not guaranteed to work, since the C++ standard permits implementations in which all-bits-zero is a trap representation of `float` or `double`. So reading those members on such an implementation would have undefined behavior.

The same applies to any padding bytes that the implementation might put between the data members -- modifying them is either undefined behavior or else puts the object into an undefined state, that has undefined behavior when used. I forget which.

In practice it will work on all implementations I know, though.

Other answers make valid points about your class being non-POD (C++03) and non-trivial (C++11). Thing is, even if you removed the constructor and called `memset` from somewhere else it would *still* not be guaranteed to work by the standard. But if you did remove the constructor you could use aggregate initialization:

```
foo f = {0};
```

and that would intialize all members to zero values (whether or not that is represented by all-bits-zero), guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

According to standard your struct is not POD type and thus it is not allowed to use memset.

## 9 Classes

> A trivial class is a class that has a default constructor (12.1), **has no non-trivial default constructors** ,
> and is trivially copyable
> 10 A POD struct108 is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no
> non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).

Since your class have non-trivial default constructor it is no longer trivial, and as result not a POD type.
Most likely is will be working on most of the compilers, no guarantee thru.